# Facebook Ads API - Actions by conversions returns total actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get info about a specific user's ad campaigns using an async request to `/reportstats`. When I add all fields to the request, everything is fine. But when I remove both `total_actions` and `total_unique_actions`, the fields `actions_28d_click_by_convs` and `unique_actions_28d_click_by_convs` return the totals instead of an object with a breakdown of totals per action. As soon as you add either `total_actions` or `total_unique_actions` back to the list, the two `by_convs` fields return the expected object.

With 'total_actions':

```
{  campaign_name: '...',
   campaign_group_name: '...',
   clicks: 337,
   reach: 80564,
   [...]
   total_actions: 335,
   actions_28d_click_by_convs: [Object],
   unique_actions_28d_click_by_convs: [Object]
}
```

Without 'total_actions':

```
{  campaign_name: '...',
   campaign_group_name: '...',
   clicks: 337,
   reach: 80564,
   [...]
   actions_28d_click_by_convs: 335,
   unique_actions_28d_click_by_convs: 335
}
```

Another weird thing: the summary of the response does show an object with the totals (of all campaigns combined) per action (e.g. post_likes).

I've tried this with 2 different users and 2 different apps, and both show the same weird thing. I (temporarily) solved it by just always requesting `total_actions`.

Anyone else who has the same problem and/or knows the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you perform the async request?  I'm using the facebook-php-ads-sdk and need to do an async request to get some old data but can't figure out how/where I need to denote the async param

Comment: @Rodney Hi, sorry for the late response. I'm using javascript so I don't know if this will help you, but when you make a request to Facebook endpoints, you need to specify some fields like `data_columns`, `time_interval` and the `access_token`. In those options you can also add a parameter: `async` which you set to `true`.